# What this graph $x^{\log y}=y^{\log x}$

Tags: logarithms, gre-exam

What is the graph of $x^{\log y}=y^{\log x}$? This question appears on GRE exam.

Comment: Take the log on both sides.

Comment: All points in the first quadrant satisfy this.

Comment: Not exactly, $x,y > 0$, otherwise $\log$ isnt defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key observation here is that
$$
x^{\log y}=(e^{\log x})^{\log y}=e^{\log(x)\log(y)}=(e^{\log y})^{\log x}=y^{\log x}
$$
for any $x,y$ such that all of these operations are defined - namely, $\{(x,y)\mid x>0\text{ and }y>0\}$.

Answer (score 5):

The three comments together answer the question. To summarize, the graph is the open first quadrant $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:x,y>0\}$, because $x^{\log y}=y^{\log x}$ for all $(x,y)$ in this set. Note that this is true whatever base is considered for the logarithm.